# Can't use Fragment from another package android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't know if im doing right thing, i make package for every separate things like accounting in my application, when i was trying to build a package for my accounting, i faced an error

> Package name is not set to a valid package name

package name was `myAccounting` so i had to make it `accounting.room`.
now when im trying to use a Fragment in an activity(activity is on that package too) raises an error in here:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_container_body, mainLoginFragment, "ex");
```

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'account.room.MainLoginFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'

Comment: Are you sure `MainLoginFragment` is a `Fragment`? If so, are you mistakenly mixing platform and support `Fragment`s?

Comment: yes im sure it extends from Fragment class @MikeM.

Comment: Which one? `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: omg! `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` @MikeM.

Comment: That's your problem. You can't mix platform and support `Fragment` stuff. If you do mean to be using support `Fragment`s, then your `Activity` should be an `AppCompatActivity`, and you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. If you don't mean to use the support classes, then change the `import` statement in `MainLoginFragment` to `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: @MikeM. this was very very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't pay attention to the Class that I've imported and now i know it's very important :

```
android.app.Fragment
```

is different from

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

and it can be you'r problem too, so mind it